# HERE API : How can i download my daily billing usage data with cost value?

Tags: billing, cost-management

I want to follow my billing usage data every month but i need daily values.
The easiest way would be to receive a monthly csv file with all details, or to have a way to retrieve it by script automatically.

Can you please explain how to proceed ?

Regard

I looked at usage data api but i can't get the cost per day.
On the bill there is no detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you talking about the the billing usage of Azure, AWS or GCP?